# Queue in and out according to clients’type

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

Queue in and out according
to clients’type
Question

Based on previous implementation, modify the LIST command, so that it will print VIP clients first
then ordinary clients in ascending order by queue number. Same as OUT command, VIP will be queued
out first then ordinary clients.

**Input**

```
IN 1000001 Ordinary

IN 2000003 VIP

IN 2000009 VIP

OUT

OUT

OUT

OUT

IN 1000007 Ordinary

IN 2000005 VIP

LIST

OUT

QUIT
```

**Output**

```
IN:1 1000001 Ordinary 0

IN:2 2000003 VIP 0

IN:3 2000009 VIP 1

OUT:2 2000003 VIP

OUT:3 2000009 VIP

OUT:1 1000001 Ordinary

FAILED:

IN:4 1000007 Ordinary 0

IN:5 2000005 VIP 0

LIST:        

5 2000005 VIP

4 1000007 Ordinary

OUT:5 2000005 VIP

GOOD BYE!
```

I have tried to make two queues one for VIP and one for Ordinary it has error  in the Enqueue function it shows weird figures for the card number and client type  but the program runs ..........any other solution is welcomed other than the two queue approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include<string.h>

int position=0;
int length=1;

typedef struct Node
{
    int record;
    int CardNum;
    char CustomerType[20];
    struct Node* next;

}Node;

typedef struct queue
{
    Node* front;
    Node* rear;
}Queue;

Queue q1,q2;

void Enqueue(Queue *q, char *x, char *y);
void List(Queue *q);

int main()
{
    char command[10];
    char card[10],*ptrcard;
    char client[10],*ptrclient;

    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%s",command);

        if(strcmp(command,"IN") == 0)
        {
            printf("IN:");

            scanf("%s",card);
            ptrcard=&card[0];

            scanf("%s",client);
            ptrclient=&client[0];


            if(strcmp(client,"VIP")==0)
            {
                Enqueue(&q1,card,client);
            }
            else if(strcmp(client,"Ordinary")==0)
            {
                Enqueue(&q2,card,client);
            }

        }
        else if(strcmp(command,"LIST") == 0)
        {
            printf("LIST:\n");
            List(&q1);
            List(&q2);
        }
        else if(strcmp(command,"QUIT") ==0)
        {
            printf("GOOD BYE!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void Enqueue(Queue *q, char *x, char *y)
{
    Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    strcpy(temp->CardNum,x);
    strcpy(temp->CardNum,y);
    temp->record=length;
    temp->next=NULL;

    if(q->front == NULL && q->rear == NULL)
    {
        q->front=q->rear=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        q->rear->next=temp;
        q->rear=temp;
    }

    printf("%d %d %s %d\n",temp->record,temp->CardNum,temp->CustomerType,position);
    position++;
    length++;
}
void List(Queue *q)
{
    Node *temp;

   if(q->front != NULL)
   {
       temp = q->front;
       while(temp != NULL)
       {
        printf("%d %d %s\n",temp->record,temp->CardNum,temp->CustomerType);
        temp = temp->next;
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: This needs more specificity. What have you tried so far to debug this? Have you narrowed it down at all?

Comment: Thats the best i can narrow will be grateful if i am further helped with ideas

Comment: You really haven't narrowed it down at all. You're saying "here's all my code" and "it's not working". That's pretty broad. You need to use a debugger (or use other debugging techniques) to trace your logic to understand more specifically where it's going wrong.

Comment: @zuherabud this is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), at least you could try narrowing down to the point where it "fails" or tell us what it means to fail.

Comment: ok let me work on that thanks guys

Comment: @Pablo i have tried to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems here.

**1. Global variables**

I don't understand the semantics of your global variables. What is `position` and
what is `length`? I mean, you update these values for every `Enqueue` call
regardless of the queue. You never really use `position` at all (ignoring the
`printf`, which I see as debugging code), so there is no point to that.

Similar for `length`. It is the length of what? You use `length` in
`Node->record`, but again, `length` gets updated every time you enqueue
something regardless of the queue.

For me these values are dependent on the queues, so they should be in struct:

```
typedef struct queue
{
    Node* front;
    Node* rear;
    int position;
    int length;
} Queue;
```

This is just an observation, this is not what is causing the problems.

**2. Global variables** (*again*)

Why do you declare `q1` and `q2` as global variables? At least in your example
there is no reason for them to be global. I'd put them in the `main` function.

The only reason I see for that would be that global variables are initialized with 0 hence you
don't have to initialize them later on, but I consider that a bad habit. Because
if you later have to change your code an put the global variables back into a
function, you may forget about the initialization and then your have undefined
behaviour. It's better to initialize a new queue when you declare one.

```
int init_queue(Queue* queue)
{
    if(queue == NULL)
        return 0;

    memset(queue, 0, sizeof *queue);
    return 1;
}
```

And when you want a new queue:

```
Queue q;
init_queue(&q);
```

**3. Ignoring the compiler warnings/errors** (*mixing types*)

`Node->CardNum` is declared as `int` and you do

```
strcpy(temp->CardNum, x);
strcpy(temp->CardNum, y);
```

My compiler says:

```
a.c:81:12: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     strcpy(temp->CardNum,y);
            ^~~~
```

I think the second line is a typo of yours, you may have wanted to do
`strcpy(temp->CustomerType, y);` which is correct.

But:

1. You are trying to copy a string into an `int`, that doesn't work. Don't mix
   types.
2. What really happens is that `strcpy` begins writing in location where you
   most probably don't have read/write permission, if by some lucky coincidence
   the integer value of `temp->CarnNum` is the same as an address where you can
   write, then you are overwriting memory that you shouldn't.

A simple fix would be `temp->CardNum = atoi(y);` or better still you read the
value:

```
int cardNum;
scanf("%d", &cardNum);
```

and pass that `cardNum` integer to `Enqueue`. You would obviously need to change
the signature of the enqueue function:

```
void Enqueue(Queue *q, char *x, int y);
```

But in this case I think the best strategy is to read strings. Sure, your card
numbers seem to be integers, but management may change that later and add letters to
the card numbers or they would want to have padding 0s. For this reason treating
the card number as a string seems to be a better option. You would only need to
change the structure. You would also need to change the `printf` line in `List()`.

```
typedef struct Node
{
    int record;
    char CardNum[20];
    char CustomerType[20];
    struct Node* next;
} Node;
```

Making the small fixes I explained here, I was able to compile your code and run
it with the input you've provided. That's what I've got:

```
IN:1 1000001 Ordinary 0
IN:2 2000003 VIP 1
IN:3 2000009 VIP 2
IN:4 1000007 Ordinary 3
IN:5 2000005 VIP 4
LIST:
2 2000003 VIP
3 2000009 VIP
5 2000005 VIP
1 1000001 Ordinary
4 1000007 Ordinary
```

---

I have a few suggestions:

1. Unless 100% necessary, don't use global variables
2. When declaring a function that takes strings as arguments, and when this
   function is **not** going to manipulate the strings, it's best to declare
   them as `const char*`. This way it is clear right away that your function is
   not going to alter the strings, the user may also pass a string literal.

   ```
   void Enqueue(Queue *q, const char *x, const char *y);
   ```
3. Use better names for your variables, it's easier to follow code for
   everybody:

   ```
   void Enqueue(Queue *q, const char *cardNumber, const char *customer);
   ```
4. When reading from the user, it's always better to check that you buffers have
   enough space before writing them. For example if the user enters a very long
   card number, it may overflow the buffer when doing `strcpy`. For this reason
   it's better to use [`strncpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy), but be aware that `strncpy` might not
   write the `'\0'`-terminating byte if there is no space left in the buffer.
5. Even in a "trivial" program like yours, please free the memory you've
   allocated with `malloc` & Co. Write a `free_queue` function that does this
   job and use it before exiting the program.
6. Arrays decay into pointers when passing them to functions or assigning them
   to pointers.

   ```
   int array[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };

   int *ptr1 = array;
   int *ptr2 = &array[0];
   ```

   Both are equivalent, you don't need the `ptrcard` and `ptrclient` variables.
   This will do:

   ```
   scanf("%s", card);
   scanf("%s", client);

   Enqueue(&q1, card, client);
   ```
7. You should check the return value of `scanf`. It returns the number of tokens
   matched. You can control with it when a user inputs something you don't
   expect. In this case you could clean the buffer and ignore the line.

   ```
   while(1)
   {
       if(scanf("%s", card) != 1)
       {
           clean_stdin();
           printf("Unexpected entry: repeat command\n");
           continue; //
       }

       if(scanf("%s", client) != 1)
       {
           clean_stdin();
           printf("Unexpected entry: repeat command\n");
           continue; //
       }

       Enqueue(&q1, card, client);
   }
   ```

   A possible implementation for `clean_stdin`:

   ```
   void clean_stdin()
   {
       int c;
       while( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF));
   }
   ```