# Dequeue Queue one first then Queue two

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

> i want to dequeue customers in vip queue for every out command...until when the queue is empty, and if i make an OUT command it should start to dequeue ordinary until when its empty, if both queues are empty i print FAILED...........I have a problem with the Dequeue function it doesn't Dequeue the Ordinary List if i Dequeue VIP first...but if i Dequeue the Ordinary first it doesn't Dequeue VIP. The problem just exists in the Dequeue function in the main when i call it.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    #include<string.h>


    int length=1;//for counting number of customers per day

    typedef struct Node//customer details 
    {
        int record;
        int CardNum;
        char CustomerType[20];
        struct Node* next;

    }Node;

    typedef struct queue
    {
        Node* front;
        Node* rear;
    }Queue;

    Queue q1,q2;//two queues one vip one ordinary


    void Enqueue(Queue *q, int x, char *y);
    void Dequeue(Queue *q);

    int main()
    {
        q1.front=NULL;
        q2.front=NULL;
        q1.rear=NULL;
        q2.rear=NULL;

        char command[10];
        int card;
        char client[10];

        while(1)
        {
            scanf("%s",command);

            if(strcmp(command,"IN") == 0)
            {
                printf("IN:");

                scanf("%d",&card);
                scanf("%s",client);

                if(strcmp(client,"VIP")==0)//if client is vip push in queue1
                {
                    Enqueue(&q1,card,client);
                }
                else if(strcmp(client,"Ordinary")==0)//if client is vip push in queue1
                {               
                    Enqueue(&q2,card,client);
                }
            }

            else if(strcmp(command,"OUT") == 0)
            {/*i want to dequeue vip queue for every out command when the queue is empty if i make an OUT command it should start to dequeue ordianry untill they are done if both queues are empty i print FAILED*/
                if(q1.front == NULL && q1.rear == NULL && q2.front == NULL && q2.rear == NULL)
                {
                    printf("FAILED:\n");
                }

                else if(strcmp(q1.front->CustomerType,"VIP")==0)
                {
                    Dequeue(&q1);
                    position1--;
                }
                else if(strcmp(q2.front->CustomerType,"Ordinary")==0)
                {
                    Dequeue(&q2);
                    position2--;
                }
            }
            else if(strcmp(command,"QUIT") ==0)
            {
                printf("GOOD BYE!\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void Enqueue(Queue *q, int x, char *y)
    {
        Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

        temp->CardNum=x;
        strcpy(temp->CustomerType,y);
        temp->record=length;
        temp->next=NULL;

        if(q->front == NULL && q->rear == NULL)
        {
            q->front=q->rear=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            q->rear->next=temp;
            q->rear=temp;
        }

        printf("%d %d %s %d\n",temp->record,temp->CardNum,temp->CustomerType);

        length++;
    }
    void Dequeue(Queue *q)
    {
        Node* temp;
        temp=q->front;

        if(q->front == q->rear)
        {
            q->front = q->rear = NULL;
            printf("OUT:%d %d %s\n",temp->record,temp->CardNum,temp->CustomerType);
        }
        else
        {
            q->front = q->front->next;
            printf("OUT:%d %d %s\n",temp->record,temp->CardNum,temp->CustomerType);

        }
        free(temp);

    }
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve]

Comment: The problem is in the main function the command OUT,  i just post the whole code if anyone loses track of what's going on

Comment: Please click on the link and read carefully. And then tell where's the *expected* and *actual* output from your program?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48357275/queue-in-and-out-according-to-clients-type/48361804#48361804 there is the output

Comment: No, there isn't. Please [edit] the question so that it is self-contained.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala i have provided the location in my code as comment please refer it there i want to dequeue the VIP first then Ordinary the other functions are alright I uploaded the whole code instead of the dequeue function only for anyone to follow up maybei have a problem somewhere within the dequeue function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is the comment that apparently was the answer, the original answer was not correct)

If your VIP queue (q1) is empty while the ordinary queue (q2) is not empty, q1.front is null, but despite that you are trying to read q1.front->CustomerType. This will crash or give undefined behaviour.

Naming the vipQueue and ordinaryQueue instead of q1 and q2 would make the code easier to understand.

Comment: I want to dequeue the list of all VIP then the list of all Ordinary per call of function dequeue if the list of vip is empty then start to dequeue Ordinary until its done too

Comment: So let's say VIP queue is empty: q1.front == q1.rear == null. Let's say ordinary queue is not empty: q1.front != null && q1.rear != null. Your test that checks q1.front == NULL && q1.rear == NULL, will NOT be true, because q2.front and q2.rear != NULL. The code will check strcmp(q1.front.....) but q1 is null, so this will probably crash.

Comment: ya it should print FAILED only if both queues are empty but if the VIP is empty it should dequeue Ordinary untill both the queues are empty

Comment: Again - if your ViP is empty, q1.front is null but despite that you are trying to read q1.front->CustomerType. This will crash or give undefined behaviour.

Comment: WOOOOW your the best thanks alot i was feeling demoralised with this problem everyone is not getting me and i dont know how to explain thanks for your patience

Comment: No worries, don't forget to mark this as answer if it helped you. :)